# RDS Web works but not RDS Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, rds

Why is it that I can launch an RDS session using a web browser (RD Web Access), but I can't launch the same session using the RDS desktop client mstsc?

I'm assuming the RD Web Access simply auto configures and auto launches the desktop client mstsc?  If that is the case, shouldn't I be able to manually launch the same rds session direct from the mstsc client?

Comment: Are you asking how to save MSTSC to your desktop, or why you can't have multiple log ins?

Comment: The first one I think.  I don't want to login to RDWeb and mstsc at the same time, I want log into the same account from either RDWeb or mstsc.  Basically, I want to be able to launch the rds session from either the rdweb or mstsc direct.  Not at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save details of your RDP connection to your desktop (or where ever you want)

Open the RDP

Click Options

Enter the remote location by computer (such as an IP address).

Enter the user name (prefixing the domain first before a backslash)

And then check the box to save password

And then click save after entering your user name

When you try to log in, you'll be asked for the user password at that point.

[image]